# Linq to Entities delete

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a built in way to delete with Linq to Entites, using the Primary Key.

Currently m work around is to create a Stored Procedure called DeleteTable (table being the table name)

and then in C# LINQ To Entities I just do context.DeleteTable(ID)

Is this the best way? What other options are there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to go to the database to retrieve all of the object's fields, you can create a new instance of the class, attach it to a new context, remove that, and save the changes. This lets EF generate the appropriate delete command.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  var myObject = new MyObject { ID = 3 };
  context.MyObjectSet.Attach(myObject);
  context.MyObjectSet.DeleteObject(myObject);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note: this will throw an exception of you're trying to delete an object which does not exist. That's only appropriate if you're sure the object exists.

Note 2: this assumes you've set up your entities so that the generated delete command references no other fields than the ID (meaning no Timestamp properties, or anything similar that would be included in the query)

Comment: It works, but I should have added that it only works if the EF-generated delete command references no other fields than the ID. If you have a Timestamp field, EF will include that in the generated query, but since it doesn't know the value to use, the query will be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The default way would be to query out the entity and then issue the [.DeleteObject(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx) method.

Comment: Would this not require 2 trips to the DB?

Comment: Yes.  If you don't want to map or call explicit stored procedures you have limited options.

Comment: @michael `Attaching` does not need a trip?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DbSet<T>.Remove(entity)` (Version 4.1, 4.2) or `EntitySet<T>.Remove(entity)` (Version 1.0, 4.0) methods:

```
YourDbContext.Table.Remove(entityObject);
```

Comment: Again, I think you need to select The entity before you can remove it? therefore 2 trips.. I am ybe wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to query for the entity, or you can use the `Attach` approach, suggested by @hvd

Answer (score 2):

I use to search the item(s) to delete and then delete it(them) using DeleteObject method.

```
Dim itemToDelete = (From u In db.SOME_TABLE Where u.ID = ID).FirstOrDefault
db.SOME_TABLE.DeleteObject(itemToDelete)
db.SaveChanges()
```

use this inside a try catch block

Comment: isnt this doing 2 trips to the DB? (ie. select * from some_Table where id=Id) then (delete foo from some_table where ..) ?

Comment: Yes, but if you dont want to do 2 round trips to the DB you most use SP, but you map Insert, Update and Delete commands to SP, if you dont map any of then you will get an UpdateException Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use the execute command to your needs off of the context such as:

```
mycontext.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM MYTABLE");
```

or

```
mycontext.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE MYTABLE");
```

HTH

Comment: Is there ExecuteCommand method avaialble for Link to Entites? or is it only Link to SQL?

Comment: My bad. see ExecuteStoreQuery for EF. See How to: Directly Execute Commands Against the Data Source (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx) HTH

Comment: Thanks, I never knew I could do this directly from link to entities.