# Multiple operations under linq2Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, query-optimization

I've been using Linq2Entities for quite some time now on small scale programs. So usually my queries are basic (return elements with a certain value in a specific column, add/update element, remove element,...).

Now i'm moving to a larger scale program and given my experience went with Linq2Entities and everything was fine until i had to remove a large number of elements.

In Linq2Entities i can only find a remove method that takes on entity - and so to remove 1000 elemnts i need first to retrieve them then apply a remove one by one then call savechanges.

Either i am missing something or i feel a) this is really bad performance-wise and b) i would be better off making this a procedure in the database.

Am i right in my assumptions? Should massive removals / additions be made as procedures only? or is there a way to do this efficiently with Linq2Entities that i am missing?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649795/linq-to-entities-delete

Comment: @haim770 - that linq doesn't really answer my question as it reports  to a single element being deleted and my question reports to multiple elements. Although OmegaMan's answer although not the accepted one could work on my scenario. Still my question refered to knowing wether or not i could do something like "delete from mytable where datecreated < '01-01-2010'" with Linq2Entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the primary key values then you can use the other features of the Context by creating the objects manually, setting their key(s), and attaching them to the context and setting their state to delete.

```
 var ids = new List<Guid>();
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Id = id;
                entityEntry = context.Entry(employee);
                entityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: interesting - didn't know about context.Entry or EntityState - +1 for teaching me something new - but wouldn't that result in multiple 'delete' SQL query's to the database as with context.MyTableSet.Remove(entity)?

Comment: Also - what if i want to delete not by id but by some other field (a lot more common)? like entries with creation date from before 01-01-2010? This wouldn't work then. It's not that common to have a list of ids to delete but rather a rule like created before some date or that have a relationship with a certain row in a different table - like table invoices and table invoicelines and you want to delete all invoicelines from invoice x

Comment: Yea, EF isn't going to be able to optimize it like you could.  When deleting that many records I do it at the database.  Anything in bulk really I tend to go with a stored proc.  EF isn't very good at dealing with large record counts and performance can become a real issue as the context fills up with records.

Comment: If you wanted to delete by date you would have to query for the id's first then attach the entities as deleted.  EF doesn't support what you are asking for.  If you have to use use EF then you have to query.  The best you can do is just query the id so the rest of the record isn't sent across the wire and loaded into the context. context.SomeRecords.Where(x=>x.Date >= someDate).Select(x=>x.Id).ToList()

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspitions on the frameworks limitations Chow

Comment: The behavior would be the same regardless of which technique you used.  I'm not sure if EF still has to do it one at a time with a full trip back and forth or it has gotten better at sending them together.

Comment: Depends of what you call 'technique'. With ExecuteCommand i can do it all in one round trip, even removing the need to get ids first. - context.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE DateCreated < '01-01-2010'"); - of course that's not Linq2Entities anymore - but since per your answer it's not possible with Linq2Entities...

Comment: the 'techniques' I was comparing was fetching into the context or attaching to the context as being the same.  It took me awhile to accept it because I really wanted to stay 'pure' and just use EF but in a similar case recently for deletes as well as some bulk copying I had to bite the bullet and use ExecuteCommand.

Comment: looks like the way i will be going too - one has to be flexible for cases like this. Was really hoping for a entities way of doing this. something like context.MyTable.RemoveAll(entity => entity.DateCreated < someDate); would have been awesome - oh well